# How to change the UI.Button background programatically in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title, I'm stuck changing the background of the UI.Button in unity by C#.Can you help me  :).I read the UI.Button API and saw that it has a property called image. I tried to construct an image and assigned it to the Button. image but it didn't work!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your button in the hirerarchy is named button, this should call it :

```
GameObject button;

void Start() {
button = GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform.Find("button").gameObject;
}
```

In order to set the image:

```
button.GetComponent<Image>().mainTexture = /* Texture goes here */;
```

And don't forget! When working on UI elements, you need to always start your C# script by calling the UI library :

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to not use Find("button"), cause it can lead to run time errors, because `GameObject.Find(objectname)` relays on the name of the object and if you change the name....awful stuff can happen ;) 
serialize it instead:

`[SerializeField] Button myButton = null;`

then just drag the buttonreference to the object with that assigned script in the editor and call: 
`myButton.image.color = Color.white;`

if you want to change the texture use:

`myButton.image.sprite = mySprite; //reference sprite in script too`

This only works if you use Unity 4.6 and above and  as @Zee said  you need to import the UnityEngine.UI

Hope that helps :)